# Cambiar el texto del botón regresar del navigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hola como puedo cambiar el texto del boton regresar del navigation bar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

No se sabe como haces la transición, pero imagino que con un segue. Puedes hacer esto:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
backItem.title = "Me vuelvo"
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
```

}

Comment: Gracias! me funciono perfecto.

Answer (score 1):

Si estás usando Swift 3 , puedes hacerlo así :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    backItem.title = "Atrás"
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
}
```

Comment: Gracias! me funciono perfecto.